# WPF Transforms movement

Tags: wpf

Ive done some tranforms for my object in the canvas, like rotating and transforming.

How can i store the new coordinates afterwards? If I try to move the object around it will only use the new Transforms.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, this is fairly non-trivial.  Generally, you'll want to let WPF handle that kind of thing for you.

That said, here's what I've been able to come up with, [based on information from here](http://blogs.msdn.com/llobo/archive/2006/05/02/Code-for-getting-screen-relative-Position-in-WPF.aspx).  Given a text block "textBlockName":

```
HwndSource hwndSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(textBlockName) as HwndSource;

Visual root = hwndSource.RootVisual;

// Translate the point from the visual to the root.

GeneralTransform transformToRoot = textBlockName.TransformToVisual(root);

Point p = new Point(0,0);

p = transformToRoot.Transform(p);

p = hwndSource.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.Transform(p ) ;

//Display the top left point of the text box, after transforms.
MessageBox.Show(p.ToString() );
```

Edit: Looking at this further, I cannot find a better solution to this.  This seems to handle every situation I can think to throw at it, though.

Comment: Actually i manage to do it without transforms at all. I use bitmaps own Rotate etc.